# How to anchor a tabbed ViewController to the top of the TabBar at the bottom of the screen programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I had a single screen ios app and I wanted to add a second tab, so I created a separate class TabBarController and made my original app screen and a new screen the two tabs.

It works fine, except that in my single screen app, I had an element right at the bottom of the page anchored to the safe area, and now it's partially covered by the tab bar:

[image]

I am creating everything programatically (I'm terrible at using UIs, I forget where everything is).

How can I programatically anchor my bottom element to the top of the tab bar, instead of the bottom of the screen? I need to get a reference to the tab bar, but how do I get that in the child controller?

Many thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my original anchor:

```
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
            constant: VIEW_SPACER).isActive = true
```

Now I'm trying:

```
 stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.tabBarController!.tabBar.topAnchor,
            constant: VIEW_SPACER).isActive = true
```

I don't understand how my child controller can have a reference to the tabBarController, but apparently it does. But using this causes a crash. The error message seems to be:

```
'Unable to activate constraint with anchors ... because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.
```

EDIT2:
The way I set up the controllers:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
...
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let firstViewController = ViewController()
        let secondViewController = SettingsViewController()
        let tabBarList = [firstViewController, secondViewController]
        
        viewControllers = tabBarList
   }
```

Then I just made TabBarController the element in the storyboard to get instantiated as root.

Comment: Please show what have you done, you may not have added constraint from bottom of `safeArea`.

Comment: Thanks @Rob . I've added my old code and what I'm trying

Comment: This error comes when you have not added the current component to the `subview`.

Comment: Oh wait. That VIEW_SPACER is supposed to put a gap between my element and the bottom, but I've got it the wrong way round haven't I?? I'm adding to the Y value instead of substracting from it. That's not the first time I've done that. Thanks @Rob, you pointed me to exactly the right place. I've changed it and it's fine now..

Comment: @Rob I'm still curious though. How does my child ViewController come to have a reference to the TabBar?

Comment: Where have you added the childViewController? I need to see more code to understand what you have done.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I've added the code that creates the TabBarController and child views

Answer (score 2):

For your bottom constraint, you need to do it from the controller's `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`.  You should not use any constraints from the tabBar controller within your view controller as the controller is not always going to be in the tabBarController's view hierarchy.  Also, since you are setting the stackView's bottom constraint relative to the view controller, to sit higher than the controller's bottom anchor the value needs to be negative.

When a controller is added to the view hierarchy of a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`, they set the respective property on the controller(`self.navigationController`, `self.tabBarController`) so it can access it's parent controller.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let firstViewController = ViewController()
        firstViewController.title = "First"

        let secondViewController = SettingsViewController()
        secondViewController.title = "Second"

        let tabBarList = [firstViewController, secondViewController]

        setViewControllers(tabBarList, animated: false)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stackView = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.backgroundColor = .red

        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
            constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    let stackView = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.backgroundColor = .blue

        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
            constant: -1).isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image: First controller with 10 spacing]

[image: Second controller with 1 spacing]